# Can't input text on Busybox v1.27.2 built in shell (ash)

Tags: boot, fsck, busybox

I'm getting message

```
/dev/sda1 : UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY : RUN fsck MANUALLY
```

I've been searching and try to run command, but every time I inputting text it became diamond shape text

Even I can delete

(initfram) :
[image]

How can I change diamond shape text to US Keyboard text?

Comment: I wouldn't boot your system until you've fixed the problem you were told about, ie. boot 'live' media & `fsck` (*file system check*) your partitions, as your system has detected inconsistency with them which should be fixed asap to ensure no data loss. I don't understand though how diamond shape text question though.

Comment: I mean if i input "help" it became "¶¶¶¶" . instead ¶ the text became diamond shape, i cant post image here

Comment: Here is the picture https://ibb.co/VvD6DQf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diamond text is unimportant at this point. You've got a corrupt file system.

**To repair your file system...**

- at the initramfs prompt, type `fsck -f /dev/sda1`

  - if what you type is not human-readable, just type it blindly
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- at the next initramfs prompt, type `reboot` (or `exit`, then `reboot`)

  - if what you type is not human-readable, just type it blindly

**If for some reason you can't do the above, then do this...**

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda1`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: Thanks it work, although i need to install ubuntu boot first but definitely worth it!

Comment: @HanifSetyananda Great news! Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8 && busybox ash
```

Then, make sure your locale is similar to:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

You could set it by:

```
sudo update-locale LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 && . /etc/default/locale
```

If you don't want to change everything to that locale, change `LC_ALL` to `LANGUAGE` and try run busybox.

Comment: Although this answers the diamond text question, read deeper, and you'll see it doesn't solve the underlying problem, a corrupt file system. Please see my answer.

Comment: @heynnema yes, you provided good answer. I decided to answer only to minor, but direct question.

Comment: Thanks, i will do this in case i got the same problem i again